# testing redux saga callback function

Tags: redux, jestjs, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

In the saga function, after success, I am doing a callback. I tried to cover this in testing but its not getting covered. can anyone suggest some way to cover those fields.

```
export function* submitSavedDataWorker(action) {
      try {
        const response = yield call(suggestFunction, action.payload);
        const { data } = action.payload;
        yield put({
          type: actionTypes.suggestType,
          payload: response.data,
          prevData: data,
        });
        if (action.successFn) {
          action.successFn(response.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        const { charityData } = action.payload;
        yield put({
          type: actionTypes.saveFailType,
          payload: error,
          prevData: data,
        });
      }
    }
```

I have written test case like:

```
describe('submitSavedDataWorker success', ()=> {
      const it = sagaHelper(
        submitSavedDataWorker({ payload: { data: 1234 }, successFn: ()=> { return 0 } })
      );
      it("should get error as result", (result) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(
          call(suggestFunction, { data: 1234 })
        );
        return {data: true};
      });
      it("should get success as result", (result) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(
          put({
            type: actionTypes.suggestType,
            payload: true,
            prevData: 1234,
          })
        );
      });
    });
```

Comment: What does "not getting covered" mean? Do you judge by coverage report? What does it say? "cover those fields" - what fields exactly? You can start with using Jest spy as successFn.

Comment: Yes, the coverage report shows :
if (action.successFn) {
          action.successFn(response.data);
        }
is not covered.

Comment: Did you try to use a spy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sagaHelper` only advances the saga by one effect at a time when calling `it` - so the generator stops executing after yielding the `put` effect. In order for the saga to run to completion (and thus executing the uncovered lines), `it` needs to be called one more time. You can also check that the result is `undefined` to ensure that the saga has run to completion, something like:

```
      it("should complete", (result) => {
        expect(result).toBeUndefined();
      });
```

With that addition, here is the full test:

```
describe('submitSavedDataWorker success', ()=> {
      const it = sagaHelper(
        submitSavedDataWorker({ payload: { data: 1234 }, successFn: ()=> { return 0 } })
      );
      it("should get error as result", (result) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(
          call(suggestFunction, { data: 1234 })
        );
        return {data: true};
      });
      it("should get success as result", (result) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(
          put({
            type: actionTypes.suggestType,
            payload: true,
            prevData: 1234,
          })
        );
      });
      /* New code is here */
      it("should complete", (result) => {
        expect(result).toBeUndefined();
      });
    });
```